# Cyrillic inclusions

Tags: cyrillic

I want to include just a few words and letters in cyrillic in a mostly english text. For instance, I would like to write the name "Aleksandrov" in cyrillic characters. I did not find a simple way to do this and I would be grateful for some help on this matter.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `babel` package and switch to a foreign language in between your normal English text:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

text

\foreignlanguage{russian}{Видимое свечение чистых жидкостей под действием $\gamma$-радиации}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For very small Russian inserts, using the OT2 encoding might be useful because it has an easy transliteration system

[image]

The table is from an [article of mine published on ArsTeXnica](https://guitex.org/home/numero-9/146-larte-esoterica-di-scrivere-in-cirillico-con-latex-enrico-gregorio)

Here's how to get a few names:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{OT2}{\rmdefault}{wncyr}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\rn}[1]{% russian name
  {\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\rn{Aleksandrov}

\rn{Moskva}

\rn{Dostoevskii0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: see edit history for a previous solution using the `substitutefont` package, now declared obsolete.

Comment: Thank you very much for your simple and efficient answer.